# Trigger SQL update on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need some help on creating a trigger on MySQL.

I have a table "comment":

```
id_comment | id_topic | comment
```

and the "topic" table:

```
id_topic | topic | comments_ammount
```

I need to increase `comments_ammount` for each insert on "comment" table which has the same `id_topic` of the topic.

I never used triggers, so anyone can help me?

Comment: There's quite a good description on http://dev.mysql.com/ Give it a go and see if you hit any issues

Answer (score 0):

well ,i am not special in mysql but i think you can do something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
declare @x table(id_topic int)
insert into @x   '@x hold last insert'
select * 
from comment
order by id desc
limit 1
update topic t join @x c 
on c.id_topic =t.id_topic
set  comments_ammount=comments_ammount+1
DELIMITER $$
DELIMITER ;
```